# Django Ajax posting duplicate values to the view

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

Im trying to post the value of a html item(the id of the item) to the view so it can add the item to the cart, however it always posts the value of the last item printed by the django {% for %} even though the html source says the values are different

here is my html

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3" data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }'>
        {% for product in products %}
            <div class="col mb-4">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    {% if product.image %}
                        <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ product.description }}">
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ product.description|slice:":100" }}...</p>
                        <p class="card-text">${{ product.price }}</p>
                        <p>
                            <a class="btn btn-dark gap-2 mb-1" href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">View Item</a>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="add-to-cart" value="{{ product.id }}">Add to Cart</button>
                        </p>
                        {% if product.in_stock == False %}
                        <p>
                            Item is currently out of stock
                        </p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Ajax

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-to-cart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "add_to_cart" %}',
        data: {
            productid: $('#add-to-cart').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
            action: 'post'
        },
        success: function(json){

        },
        error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {

        }
    });
})
```

Here is my view

```
def CartAddView(request):
cart = Cart(request)
if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
    product_id = int(request.POST.get('productid'))
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.add(product=product)
    response =JsonResponse({
        'price': product.price,
        'id': product.id, (here the id returned is always the id of the last element printed by the loop)
    })
    return response
```

i tried to make a product detail page and when i call the ajax it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

when form submit and view return response page will reload the same page and call POST again, I fixed it with

1. create a new route but render the same page (if you want to render the same page)
2. change API return `return HttpResponseRedirect('url-new')`
   examaple:

```py
def CartAddView(request):
cart = Cart(request)
if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
    product_id = int(request.POST.get('productid'))
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.add(product=product)
    response =JsonResponse({
        'price': product.price,
        'id': product.id, (here the id returned is always the id of the last element printed by the loop)
    })
    return HttpResponseRedirect('url')
```